# Por qué el cierre precipitado de la pregunta "Como llamar metodo dentro de otro"

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, revisión-de-pregunta

Me ha pasado bastantes veces que estoy escribiendo una respuesta a una pregunta, hago las pruebas pertinentes del código, y cuando al fin estoy listo para publicar la respuesta, me topo con que la pregunta ya ha sido eliminada, o bien ha sido cerrada por supuesto duplicado (publicando un enlace a una pregunta parcialmente relacionada pero que no satisfece la pregunta original.)

Me pasó hace poco con [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83360/como-llamar-metodo-dentro-de-otro-poo-y-php), el usuario pregunta por algo conocido como [encadenamiento de métodos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), no obstante [el enlace publicado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82500/php-funciones-m%C3%A9todos-de-instancia-var%E2%86%92funcargs%E2%86%92func2args) por el que cierra es más enfocado a punteros que la metodología y filosofía detrás del *method chaining*.

OS propongo poner advertencias en lugar del cierre inmediato... si pasado un tiempo no hay respuestas y tampoco una edición que se proceda a cerrar/ marcar como duplicado la pregunta, no obstante el cierre precipitado hará perder horas a alguien que ya está preparando una respuesta bastante elaborada...

Comment: Quizá nos ayudaría que pusieras algún ejemplo de preguntas cerradas, ya que normalmente en mi opinión reconocer preguntas susceptibles de ser ceradas suele ser (en un porcentaje muy alto de ocasiones) bastante sencillo. Y además, si consideras que el cierre no ha sido correcto, siempre puedes editar la pregunta para mejorarla o marcarla como susceptible de reapertura

Comment: Me pasó hace poco [con esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83360/como-llamar-metodo-dentro-de-otro-poo-y-php), el usuario pregunta por algo conocido como [encadenamiento de métodos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), no obstante [el enlace publicado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82500/php-funciones-m%c3%a9todos-de-instancia-var%e2%86%92funcargs%e2%86%92func2args) por el que cierra es más enfocado a punteros que la metodología y filosofía detrás del `method chaining`.

Comment: Pues yo no entiendo de ese tema, pero en los comentarios el propio OP agradece al que lo marcó como duplicado: _Wou, excelente gracias por la ayuda Juan y Kenny, lo tendré en cuenta para futuras preguntas. Acertados y rápidos... Y de eso se trataba Juan, gracias. Con eso aprendí a hacerlo_

Comment: Me ha pasado alguna vez también. Ahora antes de responder una pregunta primero intento valorarla >:)

Comment: El `method chaining` utliza punteros a esctructuras de datos, por tanto se responde parcialmente la pregunta, no obstante no responde en su totalidad la filosofía detrás de él, ¿Por qué se usa?, ¿Por qué lo usan las librerías que utilizo?, Un ejemplo práctico mostrando el problema que resuelve, etc...

Comment: Por otro lado, @EduenSarceño, tambien tienes otra opción: Realizar tu mismo una pregunta autorespondida.

Comment: @EduenSarceño Se cerró así de rápido porque fue el propio autor de la pregunta que lo aceptó como duplicado... Por eso, el usuario Comunidad es quien toma la autoría del cierre (se ve en quienes cerraron la pregunta, que el último usuario es Comunidad).

Comment: @Pikoh empezaré a hacerlo, como wiki de comunidad para que no sea mal visto.

Comment: @Mariano desconozco la metodología para cerrar, pero repito, me ha pasado bastantes veces, en este caso puede que el usuario mismo haya aceptado la respuesta porque resuelve parcialmente su duda, no obstante para algún usuario más no le parece lo suficientemente clara o suficiente por lo que seguirá investigando por cuenta propia en lugares más esotéricos.

Comment: Como digo @EduenSarceño, nadie te impide añadir una pregunta/respuesta si sientes que es interesante para la comunidad. Y no creo que sea necesario ponerlo como wiki de comunidad si tu haces todo el trabajo,nadie debe verlo mal. Un _wiki de comunidad_ es para que cualquiera pueda modificar/ampliar/aportar a la respuesta. De todas maneras, debes entender que,mientras no se modifique la filosofia del sitio, aqui se trata de responder a **preguntas concretas**. Para temas amplios existen otros recursos a disposición

Comment: @EduenSarceño esperaría que antes de realizar una proposición en Meta hayas investigado todos los temas de la ayuda para entender el funcionamiento del sitio, al igual que hayas revisado otras preguntas relacionadas (que hay varias). Para empezar, el cierre se describe en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions y https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions y encontrarás preguntas en Meta en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cierre-de-preguntas?sort=votes

Comment: Yo opino que no cerramos lo suficientemente rápido, pero es que antes los requisitos para moderar eran mas bajos y con la graduación hay menos votadores, por lo que se cierran más lento.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En este caso se cerró así de rápido porque el autor de la pregunta aceptó que era duplicada.

Pero el autor es tan susceptible de equivocarse como cualquiera. Tienes que evaluar tu respuesta:

**Si es una respuesta valida para la pregunta que se afirma se ha duplicado:**
Publícala en esa otra pregunta.

**Si tu respuesta no sería válida para esa otra pregunta:**
Entonces es un falso duplicado.
Dos preguntas P y Q son duplicadas si y solo si para toda Respuesta R se cumple Val(R,P)==Val(R,Q).
Donde Val(R,X) nos dice si R es una respuesta válida para la pregunta X.

En este caso pulsa el enlace de reabrir si tienes al menos 3000 de reputación. Haz una pregunta en meta sobre esto (no edites esta) independientemente de la reputación que tengas. Pon en esa pregunta el contenido de tu respuesta y explica por qué no es una respuesta buena para la pregunta original pero sí es una respuesta buena para la pregunta falsamente marcada como duplicada.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, sobre todo por tener claro el concepto de duplicados (comúnmente mal interpretado).

Comment: Gracias @Jose Antonio Dura Olmos, marco como resuelto el tema.